# How do I get key-value pair from array of JavaScript objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hashmap

I have

```
var results = {};
```

I wrote code that populates results (from an HTTP GET request) with data in this format:

```
({
    "result":[
    {
        "Longitude" : "-097.722382",
        "Zipcode" : "78751",
        "ZipClass" : "STANDARD",
        "County" : "TRAVIS",
        "City" : "AUSTIN",
        "State" : "TX",
        "Latitude" : "+30.310606"
    }
]}
)
```

However, I want results to have `TRAVIS` as a key, and then add another variable called `count`, which counts how many total are in that county.

I'm having trouble accessing keys & values; I always seem to get `undefined`. How do I go about accessing the keys?

Here's my code. Essentially, I'm going through a bunch of zip codes, filtering out only the ones that are in Texas.

```
var i = 0;
var results = {};



/*
var results = {
  'TRAVIS': 10,
  'DALLAS': 15,
};

*/

function getValues(obj, key) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getValues(obj[i], key));
        } else if (i == key) {
            objects.push(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}




callback = function(response) {
  //console.log('callback('+i+')');
  var str = '';
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });



  response.on('end', function () {
      console.log('Processing: ' + i);
      // TODO: Parse JSON
      str = str.replace(/['\(\)]/g, "");
        if(str.substring(0,1) == "{"){

      JSON.parse(str);
}





    if(str.substring(0,1) == "{"){

      if( (str.substring(str.search("\"State\"") + 10, str.search("\"State\"") + 14)) == "\"TX\"")
       {  //console.log("THIS IS FROM TEXAS ");

          results[i] = str; 



       }
     }



    setTimeout(function() {
      i++;
      if (i >= data.length) {
        console.log(results);


      } else {
        fetch();
      }
    }, 1000)
  });
}


function fetch() {
  //console.log('fetch('+i+')');
  var options = {
    host: 'gomashup.com',
    path: '/json.php?fds=geo/usa/zipcode/'+ JSON.parse(data[i].zip)
  };
  http.request(options, callback).end();
}

fetch();
```

Comment: How can we know what's wrong if you don't show us your non-working code?

Comment: is your requirement to separate out the values from the populated result?

Answer (score 1):

```
var response = ({
    "result":[
    {
        "Longitude" : "-097.722382",
        "Zipcode" : "78751",
        "ZipClass" : "STANDARD",
        "County" : "TRAVIS",
        "City" : "AUSTIN",
        "State" : "TX",
        "Latitude" : "+30.310606"
    }
]});

You can excess key and value this way...

console.log(response.result[0].County);
console.log(response.result[0].Zipcode);
And also add a key ......
response.result[0].count = 134;
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a loop that goes through several zip codes. So how would I make this work for all of them? I can't do a generic format with concatenation because I would need to access the keys & values of results, which I can't do right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash library to filter your result.

```
let _ = require("lodash");

let res = {
    result: [
        {
            "Longitude": "-097.722382",
            "Zipcode": "78751",
            "ZipClass": "STANDARD",
            "County": "TRAVIS",
            "City": "AUSTIN",
            "State": "TX",
            "Latitude": "+30.310606"
        },
        {
            "Longitude": "-097.722382",
            "Zipcode": "78751",
            "ZipClass": "STANDARD",
            "County": "TRAVIS",
            "City": "AUSTIN",
            "State": "TX",
            "Latitude": "+30.310606"
        },
        {
            "Longitude": "-097.722382",
            "Zipcode": "78751",
            "ZipClass": "STANDARD",
            "County": "abc",
            "City": "AUSTIN",
            "State": "TX",
            "Latitude": "+30.310606"
        }
    ]
}

function test() {
    let groupedResult = _.groupBy(res.result, 'County')
    result = {}
    _.forEach(Object.keys(groupedResult), (County)=>{
        result[County] = groupedResult[County].length
    })
    console.log(result)
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `eval(%yourcode%)`, it will return you an object which has one key 'result' which is pointing at array with only one value inside - an array with your info pairs. So to access these keys, you have to iterate this object - `eval(%yourcode%)['result'][0]`, like this:

```js
initialString = '({"result":[{"Longitude" : "-097.722382","Zipcode" : "78751","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "TRAVIS","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"}]})';
    
myObj = eval(initialString)['result'][0];

for (key in myObj) { 
  document.write(key + ': ' + myObj[key] + '<br>'); 
}
```

For example, if you gonna have your result object to contain many objects, you should iterate through `(myObj = eval(initialString)['result'])`, like this:

```js
initialString = '({"result":[{"Longitude" : "1","Zipcode" : "78751","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "TRAVIS","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "2","Zipcode" : "78751","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "TRAVIS","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "3","Zipcode" : "78751","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "TRAVIS","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"}]})';
    
myObj = eval(initialString)['result'];

myObj.forEach(function(infoItem,index) {
  document.write('Item #' + (index+1) + "<br>");
  for (key in infoItem) { 
    document.write('&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + key + ': ' + infoItem[key] + '<br>'); 
  }
});
```

Oh, if you want to create 'result' object which will contain county as key and zipcode as value, you can do it this way:

```js
// in this example `myObj` has 3 objects inside itself
// we iterate through each and select values that we need

var initialString = '({"result":[{"Longitude" : "1","Zipcode" : "78751","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "TRAVIS","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "2","Zipcode" : "37465","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "SOMECOUNTY","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "3","Zipcode" : "90210","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "MYBELOVEDCOUNTY","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"}]})',
    result = {};

myObj = eval(initialString)['result'];

myObj.forEach(function(infoItem,index) {
  // here we create entries inside 'result' object
  // using county values as keys
  result[infoItem['County']] = infoItem['Zipcode'];
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result,null,'<br>'));
```

Sorry, i finally got what you need) Look:

```js
// in this example `myObj` has 4 objects inside itself
// we iterate through each and select values that we need

var initialString = '({"result":[{"Longitude" : "1","Zipcode" : "78751","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "TRAVIS","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "2","Zipcode" : "37465","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "SOMECOUNTY","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "3","Zipcode" : "90210","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "MYBELOVEDCOUNTY","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"},{"Longitude" : "4","Zipcode" : "90210","ZipClass" : "STANDARD","County" : "MYBELOVEDCOUNTY","City" : "AUSTIN","State" : "TX","Latitude" : "+30.310606"}]})',
    result = {};

myObj = eval(initialString)['result'];

myObj.forEach(function(infoItem,index) {
  // here we create entries inside 'result' object
  // using county value as a keys

  // first we check if an entry with current key exists
  if (result[infoItem['County']]) {
    // if yes, just increment it
    result[infoItem['County']]++;
  } else {
    // if no, make it equal to 1
    result[infoItem['County']] = 1;
  }
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(result,null,'<br>'));
```

Comment: Thank you. But since it's a loop (the one I posted was just an example), and there are several zip codes, what would I put inside of 's'?

Comment: Do I have to start out with actual data? Is there a way I can just do a generic string for initialString? The problem I'm running into again is trying to concatenate str[i].County (for example), but I can't access the keys. If that makes sense.

Comment: Look at my answer again) Is that what you need? Actually i can't understand what youre going to achieve)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a library like underscore? The could achieve this with the [groupBy and map functions](http://underscorejs.org/#map).

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(response.result, function(item){
  return item.County;
});
var result = _.each(grouped, function(value, key, list){
  return list[key] = value.length;
});
```

Take a look at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fNOWPYBPsaNNDVX3M904

Answer (score 0):

since youre using nodejs you could install the string store npm module. It converts it into an array and the values can be used easily. more details here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/stringstore

Comment: Answers to questions should not be contained in links as they will change over time.  Leave the link as a reference, but the answer should be migrated to this site if applicable.